# Launching Intent using userID with if block

Tags: java, android

I have this activity class that won't catch the if block. Because I'm a beginner, I couldn't think of any other way to catch the given userID("001") to launch a specific intent(AdminTab) after the Splash Thread.

Could someone please help me point out what i'm doing wrong or advice me with some sample code? Thank you!

public class Splash extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer = new Thread(){

    public void run(){

    String id = "";
    id = userFunction.getID(getApplicationContext());

    try{
        sleep(1000);
        //Should open AdminTab if user id is "001"      
        if("001".equals(id)){

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                    AdminTab.class);

                    startActivity(i);

        }else{

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                    UserTab.class);

                    startActivity(i);
        }

        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {


        }
    }

    };

    timer.start();
}
```

This is the getID method from UserFunctions Class.
getUserID from a sqlite database handler.

UserFunctions.java

```
public String getID(Context context) {
    String id = "";
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getUserID();

    if(cursor != null) {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            id = cursor.getString(0);
        }
    } else {
        id = "";
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, are you getting an error?

maybe change it to id.equals("001")

If this isn't the main activity why don't you just send the id through in the intent if required?

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. No. I'm not getting any error. but like i said, it won't catch the if block.. I already tried id.equals("001") but it didn't work. This works as the main activity since it's the splash activity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no prob in "001".equals(id).

Please check the id that you are getting from getID(). There is some problem with the id that you are fetching from the database. Try to print the value and cross check.